# Deploying Xamarin app to iPhone - unhelpful "Deploy failed" message

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin, monogame

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 for Windows, paired to a Mac Mini (which has an iPhone plugged into it).  When I try to build-and-deploy my app to the remote iPhone, the build works but the deployment fails instantly.  All I get from the Build window output is this very unhelpful pair of lines:

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: SS1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Deploy failed
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 11:09 AM and took 02:44.424 minutes ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy completed at 11:09 AM and took 02:44.425 minutes ==========
```

My app uses MonoGame 3.8 but I don't know how relevant that is.  I managed to get the "Platformer2D" MonoGame sample app to work.  In other words, I can build that sample code and deploy it to the iPhone.  I've looked for obvious differences between this project and mine, but it's difficult because the deployment output gives me no clue as to what the problem could be.

I turned on "Diagnostic" level build logging in Visual Studio.  This produce 190K lines of output for the build, but still only those two lines for the deployment :-(.

I have captured the iPhone device log during the process, but I can't see anything in it (error or otherwise) related to a possible deployment.

I have tried using .NET 6 on the current production Visual Studio version (i.e. TargetFramework="net6.0-ios"), and also .NET 8 on the upcoming Visual Studio Preview ("net8.0-ios").  I get the same problem either way.

Any ideas as to how I could get more helpful output than just "Deploy failed"?  For example, is there anything written somewhere on the Mac?

---

**UPDATE:** I have found that my build is being saved within the Library/Cache/Xamarin/mtbs folder on my Mac.  Using the "ios-deploy" tool from GitHub (running in a Terminal window on the Mac) I am able to deploy the app to my iPhone!  So why can't Visual Studio do the same thing?!

Comment: I suggest you check your apple development certificate and make sure you have the correct, current cert installed (with the private key) and that the phone you are using is associated with your Apple Developer account. If that's all good, you could _try_ installing Visual Studio for Mac on the mac and running it from there.  No guarantee it'll help, but it removes one moving part.   Can you run it on a simulator?  Obviously worth uninstalling any previous version of your app on the phone and rebooting everything.

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty project to check if it can be successfully deployed to an iOS device?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, as I said, I've gone quite a bit further than that.  The Platformer2D MonoGame sample is quite a complex app, and it deploys to the iOS device just fine.  But I can't see why it works where my app (which is similar in many ways) fails.  That's why I'd like to get more diagnostic info from the deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I switched to another branch of my code and that one deploys just fine.  Unfortunately I really didn't learn anything about why VS dislikes my other branch so much, so I can't offer any insights to anyone who encounters this in future.